# Can I directly upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04?

Tags: upgrade

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS version. Now I want to upgrade to 14.04 LTS. Can I directly upgrade to 14.04, or I have to update first to 13.04 & then 14.04?

Comment: You can, and should, upgrade directly to 14.04.

Comment: if you upgrade to using update manager it will use internet to download packages, you need to have good download speed otherwise it will take lot of time ! or you can do is download iso image the burn it then use it to upgrade

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you take a backup of your data and do a fresh install instead.

However, if you wish to upgrade, enter the following commands in the terminal

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get upgrade`

`sudo update-manager -d`

Now your Update Manager will open and it will show the availability of the upgrade. Click on the `Upgrade` button.

Answer (score 0):

Run `do-release-upgrade`
That is what Ubuntu prompts me to do whenever I login (via the terminal)

```
New release '14.04.1 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.
```

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, you can directly upgrade.**

You can always upgrade from one release to the immediate next release.  In addition to this you can always upgrade from one LTS release to the next LTS release.

Upgrade in the normal way, either through the GUI through `do-release-upgrade` in the console (you don't need `sudo` in front of that command).